# Where is my mistake and how can i correct it?

Tags: matlab, debugging, syntax-error

I'm using this code for parameter estimation. it gives me an error in line given below. how can i correct this. thanks in advance.

```
while dcnorm>1E-6 & iter<10

f=a*(b.^(c.^t))-y;

Ji1=b.^(c.^t); 
Ji2=a*(b^(c.^(t-1)))*(c.^t);    %ERROR LINE
Ji3=a*(b^(c.^t))*ln(b)*t*(c.^(t-1));

J=[Ji1 Ji2 Ji3];
dc=-J\f; tahmin=tahmin+dc; 

dcnorm=norm(dc); iter=iter+1;

a=tahmin(1); b=tahmin(2); c=tahmin(3); 

D=[iter a b c norm(f) norm(dc)]
end
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try (explicitly use element-wise operations throughout the expression):

```
Ji2=a.*(b.^(c.^(t-1))).*(c.^t);
```

My guess you'll need to modify the next line as well.

Comment: please write Ji3 as well. "Ji3=a.*(b.^(c.^t))*log(b).*t*(c.^(t-1));" also gives an error.

Comment: @mert you'll have to show some effort on your part as well. please READ my answer. Try and UNDERSTAND it - in what way is it different than your original code and why this difference is working. Now try and APPLY the same reasoning to the next line of code.

Comment: of course i tried . but when i applied it, code gave a matrix warning "rank deficient" so i asked it again. sorry. anyway i will try to change it.

Comment: Other questions and answers on SO might also help you to debug your problem. [This Q&A deals with the "rank deficient" issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585472/warning-rank-deficient-matlab)